# Android app working on emulator but not on a real device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Just wrote this simple app for testing, a button that display the output with a `spellcheckersession`.

It works fine on Emulator but don't work when i try to run the app on a real device (Note2 running android4.4.2).

Can someone help me understand why?

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.kevin.spellchecks;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.textservice.SentenceSuggestionsInfo;
import android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession;
import android.view.textservice.SuggestionsInfo;
import android.view.textservice.TextInfo;
import android.view.textservice.TextServicesManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SpellCheckerSession.SpellCheckerSessionListener{
    TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;
    Button b1;
    EditText et1;
    private SpellCheckerSession mScs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);

        final  String[][] T9 = {
                /* 0 */ {"a", "b", "c"},
                /* 1 */ {"d", "e", "f"},
                /* 2 */ {"g", "h", "i"},
                /* 3 */ {"j", "k", "l"},
                /* 4 */ {"m", "n", "o"},
                /* 5 */ {"p", "q", "r", "s"},
                /* 6 */ {"t", "u", "v"},
                /* 7 */ {"w", "x", "y", "z"}
        };
        final ArrayList<String> prevalue = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayList<String> buff = new ArrayList<String>();
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                prevalue.clear();
                buff.clear();
                tv1.setText("");
                tv2.setText("");
                tv3.setText("");

                for(int et = 0; et< et1.length(); et++) {
                    String subvalue = et1.getText().toString().substring(et, et + 1);
                    if(prevalue.size() !=0){
                        buff.add(prevalue.toString());
                        prevalue.clear();
                    }
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < T9[Integer.parseInt(subvalue)].length; ii++) {
                        if(buff.size() != 0){
                            String[] buffarray = buff.toString().split("\\s*,\\s*");
                            for(int ba = 0; ba<buffarray.length; ba++){
                                prevalue.add(buffarray[ba].toString() + T9[Integer.parseInt(subvalue)][ii].toString());
                            }
                        }else{
                            prevalue.add(T9[Integer.parseInt(subvalue)][ii]);
                        }
                    }
                    buff.clear();
                }
                tv1.append("prevalue size: " + prevalue.size() + '\n');
                for(int lp = 0; lp < prevalue.size(); lp++){
                    String without1 = prevalue.get(lp).toString().replace("[", "");
                    String without2 = without1.replace("]", "");
                    tv1.append(without2 + '\n');
                    try{
                        mScs.getSuggestions(new TextInfo(without2.toString()), 1);
                    }catch (Exception e){
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        final TextServicesManager tsm = (TextServicesManager)
                getSystemService(Context.TEXT_SERVICES_MANAGER_SERVICE);
        mScs = tsm.newSpellCheckerSession(null, null, this, true);
    }
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mScs != null) {
            mScs.close();
        }
    }
    public void onGetSuggestions(final SuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < arg0.length; ++i) {
            final int len = arg0[i].getSuggestionsCount();
            sb.append('\n');
            for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j) {
                sb.append(arg0[i].getSuggestionAt(j));
            }
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                tv2.setText(tv2.getText().toString() + sb.toString() + "");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onGetSentenceSuggestions(SentenceSuggestionsInfo[] arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kevin.spellchecks.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/btn1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/tv3" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/et1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Original"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="SpellCheck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.kevin.spellchecks">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.kevin.spellchecks"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by not working? Are you getting any error message ?

Comment: There will have a error if you remove the try catch Exception before the onResume when you start the app.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I just loaded and ran it on a Samsung S5. More info would help, like, does it load, does your device come up as connected? How far do you get?

Comment: Suppose there will have a new value showing in textview(tv2) by the runOnUithread to get the suggestion word by the spellchecker session. It dose not work when run in a real device.